# RCA tablet want to watch on monitor

Tags: kernel

I have an inexpensive tablet (RCA), and I want to hook it up to a monitor with a VGA hookup, I got the adaptor, micro USB on one side and VGA on the other. Hooked it all up, and nothing....I can't figure out what is wrong...is my device just too cheap, and can't send a signal to the monitor? Please help!!!

Thank you,

Cherie